# Rag & Bone Wish List killing monsters

Tags: oldschool-runescape

Do I really have to kill all the monsters to finish the (mini)quest or is it possible to buy some bones of the ge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the bones required to the Wish List are all non-tradeable and cannot be purchased through the Grand Exchange.

Below are a couple of the bones, which says that they are non-tradable. I flipped through most of the bones and they all say the same thing

> [Orgre Ribs](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Ogre_ribs): Tradeable? No
>
> [Jorge Bone](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Jogre_bone): Tradeable? No
>
> [Werewolf Bone](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Werewolf_bone): Tradeable? No
>
> [Zorge Bone](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Zogre_bone): Tradeable? No

Comment: Damn, now I see it. Jorge Bone(untradeable, needed for the quest) --- Jorge Bones(tradeable, standard drop). This goes on for all the required bones/rib/claws and what not.